# Can someone give me tips with this surface integral

Tags: vector-fields, surface-integrals

The integral is like this $$\int \int _Sx(z^2+3x^2)dydz+y(x^2+3y^2)dzdx+z(y^2+3z^2)dxdy$$ where $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=2$

Someone suggested to try with the divergence theorem, but I don't really know how.
What i do know is that S is a sphere with normal in (x,y,z) and i need to find a link in the summands but I don't really know how. I can't really see how to form the vector field for this. Thanks for reading, english is not my native language and it is a bit hard to express all this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector-field is
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r})=(x(z^2+3x^2), y(x^2+3y^2), z(y^2+3z^2)))^T$$
And by the divergence theorem, we have that
$$\int_S \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} = \int_{V} \text{div}(\vec{F)} \mathrm{d}V$$
$$= \int_{V} z^2+9x^2+x^2+9y^2+y^2+9z^2 \mathrm{d}V$$
$$= 10\int_{V} x^2+y^2+z^2 \mathrm{d}V$$
$$= 10\int_{V} r^2 \mathrm{d}V$$
Can you continue?